# Displaying JSON data in jQuery accordion

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-easyui

I'm working on putting together a new app and decided to try using jQuery EasyUI to make things easier for me.  I'm making progress, but I'm definitely over my head.  This is a -learn-as-I go kind of effort.

Here's where I am: 
  I have been able to pull basic contact information and populate this into a jQuery dialog window.  I'm customizing the dialog with tabs and an accordion in one of these tabs.  My problem is that the accordion is displaying the JSON- and I can't seem to format it.

Here is the code for this section:

```
function editUser(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Prospect Details');
            $('#fm').form('load',row);
            url = 'update_user.php?id='+row.id;
            $('#dia_name').html(row.Name);
            var phone = phoneFormat(row.Phone);
            $("#dia_phone").html(phone);
            if (row.message_duration > 0) {
                $('#hangup').hide();
                $('#message').show();
                $('#msg_txt').show();
            } else {
                $('#hangup').show();
                $('#message').hide();
                $('#msg_txt').hide();
            }
            var pp = $('#aa').accordion('getSelected'); // get the selected panel
            if (pp){
                pp.panel('refresh','contact_history.php?phone='+row.Phone); // call 'refresh' method to load new content
                var txt1=$("<p>Time: ").text(contact_dt);
                var txt2=$("</p><p>Method: ").text(method);
                var txt3=$("</p><p>Who: ").text(who);
                var txt4=$("</p><p>Note: ").text(note);
                $("#hist_title").append(txt1);
                $("#hist_item").append(txt2,txt3,txt4);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the HTML section of the accordion:

```
<div id="aa" class="easyui-accordion" style="width:300px;height:200px;">
                <div title="Title1" data-options="iconCls:'icon-save'" style="overflow:auto;padding:10px;">
                <p>Test</p>
                </div>
                <div id="hist_item" title="Title2" data-options="iconCls:'icon-reload',selected:true" style="padding:10px;">
                content2
                </div>
                <div title="Title3">
                content3
                </div>
                </div>
```

So now…  What incredibly obvious and stupid errors am I making here?  Thanks again in advance for helping me struggle thru this.

Comment: Where is the JSON supposed to be read?

Comment: How do you get your data from the server..?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever your JSON is coming from, you have to parse it first:

`var data = JSON.parse(incomingData);`

Then, it is an array, which you can do as you please::

`$("#hist_title").append(data['title']);`

Or

`$("#hist_title").text(data['title']);`